# Multiple rows from CSV to be returned in single line

Tags: powershell

Below code returns fine, and generates the CSV file with below data:

```
Borrowers Name
---------------

    Conrad
    Luke
    Shaw
```

Expected output: `Conrad,Luke, Shaw` (all in one line - values are separated with commas)

```
$DestinationFileName = $DestinationFile
$SourceFileName = $SourceFile
$tableNum = $tableNumber
$DatabaseTable = $DatabaseTableName

$delimiter = ','
$objWord = New-Object -Com Word.Application
$objWord.Visible = $false # $false
$objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open($SourceFileName,$false,$true)
$LETable = $objDocument.Tables.Item($tableNum)
$LETableCols = $LETable.Columns.Count
$LETableRows = $LETable.Rows.Count

$RawCSV = for($r=1; $r -le $LETableRows; $r++) {
    $content= @()
    for($c=1; $c -le $LETableCols; $c++) {
         $content += ("`"{0}`"" -f $LETable.Cell($r,$c).Range.Text -replace "(`r|`n|`t)|$([char]7)?")
    }
    $Content -join $delimiter
}
$Csv = $RawCSV | ConvertFrom-Csv
#$objDocument.Close()
$objWord.Quit()
# Stop Winword Process
$rc = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objWord)
$Csv
$Csv | Export-Csv $DestinationFileName -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will do the trick:

```
$csv.'Borrowers Name'  -join ", "
```

What you do here is to access the property you want and then use `-join` to display it in one line. You specify delimiter in double quotes so you can modify it (from your example it's not clear whether you want to have space after the comma or not).

Comment: i have to apply this to multiple files $csv.Col1 -join ", " ... trying this not working for me

Comment: That's expected, take a look at `foreach` and you should resolve it. Basically you'll have to do `$result += $csv.col1 -join ","` inside `foreach`.